# gridview with xml datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, webforms

I am new to asp.net web forms.

I have XML, like below.

```
<table>
  <row id="1" name="name1"/>
  <row id="2" name="name2"/>
  <row id="3" name="name3"/>
  <row id="4" name="name3"/>
  <row id="5" name="name3"/>
</table>
```

I want to bind this data to asp:GridView.
But only name part of xml not Id.

What I did is here, but it's not all.
I don't even know that it's proper or not.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var XmlPath = Server.MapPath("~/Data.xml");
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(XmlPath);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (XmlNode xn in doc.ChildNodes[1])
    {
        string tagName = xn.Name;
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains(tagName))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(tagName);
        }

    }
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    foreach (XmlNode xn in doc.ChildNodes[1])
    {
        dr[xn.Name] = xn.InnerText;
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

> I also have to filter data, for exa. I want to print only those data whose ID is 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LINQ to XML` like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("~/Data.xml");

var names = from r in doc.Descendants("row")
             select (string)r.Attribute("name");

GridView1.DataSource = names;
GridView1.DataBind();
```